# SQL Server : Insert Image Into Table Dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table `Products` and I want to insert an image for each in the image column based on the product **Code** where the name of the image is identical to the product **Code**.

```
UPDATE Products
   SET ProdImage = (SELECT * FROM Openrowset
   ( Bulk 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ImageCatalog\sbrk.jpg' , Single_Blob)
     as image)
 WHERE CODE = 'sbrk'
GO
```

The name of the image and the **code** is `sbrk` when I tried to make the path dynamic I get an exception:

> Expecting STRING, TEXT_LEX

Comment: Why not use SQL Server to generate static SQL for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to make the path dynamic you're going to need to use dynamic SQL. You can't just pass in a parameter into the BULK statement:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Code NVARCHAR(200)

SET @Path = 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ImageCatalog\sbrk.jpg' 
SET @Code = 'sbrk'

SET @sql = '
UPDATE Products
   SET ProdImage = (SELECT * FROM Openrowset
   ( Bulk N''' + @Path + ''' , Single_Blob)
     as image)
 WHERE CODE = ''' + @Code + ''''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**UPDATE**

Turboc has it right (No rep to comment tho). I missed the part about the image file name being the same as the code:

```
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Code NVARCHAR(200)

    SET @Path = 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ImageCatalog\' 
    SET @Code = 'sbrk'

    SET @sql = '
    UPDATE Products
   SET ProdImage = (SELECT * FROM Openrowset
   ( Bulk N''' + @Path +  @Code + '.jpg'' , Single_Blob)
     as image)
 WHERE CODE = ''' + @Code + ''''

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the @Path statement given by darksolace may need to be modified to take out the code.jpg at the end.

```
SET @Path = 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ImageCatalog\'
```

Then modify the update statement to append the code and the .jpg to the bulk subquery.  I don't have sql here with me right now so the ''''''s might be off a little.

```
UPDATE Products
   SET ProdImage = (SELECT * FROM Openrowset
   ( Bulk N''' + @Path + @Code + '.jpg''' , Single_Blob)
     as image)
 WHERE CODE = ''' + @Code + ''''
```

But I think that with what darksolace recommended should get you pretty close.